# bezier curves to flat mesh

Tags: bezier-curves

I am trying to use bezier curves to make animatable 2d objects for an animation of mine, but for some reason, whenever I click on the 2d button for making a curve 2d, there is no fill of surface. Here is the problem illustrated below.
[image]

What I want is the shape to be fill with surface mesh, but I don't know how.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: There is a menu named Fill just below the 3D button. Would you mind telling us what setting it is? Also, is your curve a closed path?

Comment: I used grease pencil to draw what I am fairly sure was a closed path, but ain't sure. Then I converted it to a bezier curve. Maybe that is what I did wrong. What I really want is some way to make grease pencil drawings animatable like normal mesh objects. For some reason, having keyframes say for grease strokes position doesn't mean that the blender will estimate the rest of the frames position. However, objects' keyframes seem to work. Maybe this is the wrong way, but I am just trying to figure out how to do simple animation with a grease pencil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The curve must be manually closed in edit mode (selecting the first and last vertex and pressing <kbd>F</kbd> to connect) and seen from top view (it should lie on a X/Y plane) to be properly filled.

If you want to animate it, check the AnimAll Addon, which can animate single points of a curve.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is there a way to make incomplete grease pencil drawings into meshes? Or, is there any way to ensure that grease pencil drawings converted to bezier curves actually are closed?